# How to add Stops or Waypoints in android google maps programmatically using Maps intent

Tags: android, google-maps

Below is the code i am using to show google map with source & destination address, But in that i need to add Stops or way points. How can I add.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + String.valueOf(currentLat) + "," + String.valueOf(currentLng) + "&daddr=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Gachibowli"+"+to:Lingampally+to:Nizampet+to:kukatpally+to:moosapet+to:Nizampet+to:srnagar+to:ameerpet+to:jubileehills+to:kothaguda";
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

"+to:" will add stops