# How to add multiple waypoints to show direct navigation from app to google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have used Intent for that

```
 Uri  IntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +locationDetails.data.latitude + ","+ locationDetails.data.latitude
+"to:"+   21.190008199999998+","+72.7963623 + "to:"+   21.200008199999998+","+72.8063623);
```

Comment: Only this code ? Any issue ?

Comment: not getting markerrs of waypoints in map

Comment: You can use direction API

Comment: how to use it for direction?

Comment: Te aa check karyu ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862623/how-to-add-stops-or-waypoints-in-android-google-maps-programmatically-using-maps @Kinjal Makwana

Comment: Is this worked for you ?

Comment: yes, thank you @Piyush

Comment: Great !! :) :) :)

Answer (score -1):

Dude, u can use this library: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

Include `compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'` in your gradle(Module:app) -> inside `dependency{}`

Please, review the examples of the lib